# Naming nesting umbrella apps in elixir

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

Umbrella apps behave very similarly to normal apps as set up by mix. They have configuration and can be started as a whole. Therefore apps can be expanded to umbrella apps as they grow. I have now got to the situation where I would like to define an umbrella app as one of the apps in a larger umbrella app.

Are there any good reasons not to do this?

Also is there a way/convention to namespace apps?
For example

```
def project do
    [app: :"analytics.web",
     version: "0.0.1",
     deps_path: "../../deps",
     lockfile: "../../mix.lock",
     elixir: "~> 1.0",
     build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
     start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
     deps: deps]
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erlang and Elixir applications in runtime have a flat namespace. They can depend on each other, creating a tree like dependency graph.

Umbrella projects (not apps, because there is no single "app") in Rebar and Mix is mostly a convenience to avoid having separate repositories for several related and/or interdependent applications.

Even if Rebar and Mix supported nested umbrella projects, I would say it is just confusing the structure of normal applications. You are pretending there is a nested namespace where there is none.

Using dots in the application name is also not the best idea, since they are problematic to enter in both Erlang (`'analytics.web'`) and Elixir (`:"a.b"`).

I would just use one umbrella project with several interdependent applications:

````
.
├── README.md
├── apps
│   ├── analytics
│   ├── analytics_stats
│   ├── analytics_web
│   ├── other_a
│   ├── other_b
│   └── ...
├── config
│   └── config.exs
└── mix.exs
```
````

Comment: saying umbrella project is, in itself, actually a pretty helpful change